# SQL Distinct count cumulative

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a query that maps the following input to the following output:

Input:

```
a,b,id    
x,y,1    
x,y,2    
x,z,3    
t,z,4    
t,y,5
t,y,6
```

Output:

```
count,id    
1,1    
1,2    
2,3    
1,4    
2,5
2,6
```

Using the following logic:

For every different group in a, count how many different b elements are for ids lower or equal than the current id.

---

I have tried:

`SELECT COUNT(a), b, id FROM table GROUP BY b`

but this doesn't give any cumulative results.

Comment: It is not, I have asked myself the other question but the idea is different!

Comment: I'm having some trouble following your description. By "group in a" do you mean just the value in column, so we just have {x,t}. If so I'm not sure how your expected results follow. For example, the first record is x,y,1 - There is no record with colA = x and id < 1, so we'd have 0. For the next record X,Y,2 we have 1 record with colA = x and id < 2, so the intuitive result set would be X,Y,2,1. etc... Is there something that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried in solving this issue?

Comment: @Error_2646 I mean lower or equal, not lower, that's why the first record has a 1 count.

Comment: @DanialWayne I have provided what I've tried so far

Comment: @DavidMasip What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct t2.b) from t t2 where t2.a = t.a and t2.id <= t.id) 
from t;
```

For performance, you want in index on `t(a, b)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is very slow for a table with 600000 elements, which is what I am dealing with now